# Attach a file to a virtual beacon using Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, beacon, android-ibeacon

I am very interested in using Android Beacon Library as it seems it can help with my project. I want to create virtual beacons using smartphones to act as if they were a beacon with an attached file, then a listening smartphone could access this text file when it detects the virtual beacon.

I have seen that there are some different ways of doing this using this library: There are data fields (Long) where I could encode a url to the file and there is also a beacon data factory that seems to be used to get information from a server but there is few documentation about this last option and I really do not know how using it.

So my questions are: Should I use the data fields or the factory for my purpose? In case of you recommend using the factory, how does it works with the notifier? Have you any example code about this?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

**The main issue with this use case is the limited number of bytes available** in standard Bluetooth LE beacon advertisements for transporting data.  Regardless of which beacon format you use (iBeacon, AltBeacon, Eddystone-UID, Eddystone-URL, etc.), you are generally limited to **a maximum of 23 usable bytes** of data space in an advertisement.  The practical number may be smaller, because you must use some bytes to identify the advertisement type, and whether it is *your* beacon vs. one belonging to somebody else.

A few points on specific formats:

- **AltBeacon**: The "long" data fields mentioned in the question, generally cannot be used for more than a single byte in common beacon formats.  The AltBeacon format has a one byte data field.  The fact that the Java data type is long does not change that only one byte is available in this beacon format.
- **Eddystone-URL**: This beacon format is designed to transport URLs of up to 17 bytes in length, and includes special expansion byte codes to help make them shorter.  You can use a URL compressor to make any URL fit in this space.

The DataFactory you describe in the question is used to hook in to a third-party cloud data store to attache key/value pairs to your beacon.  The only known implementation using this feature is the paid [ProximityKit](https://proximitykit.radiusnetworks.com/) service from RadiusNetworks.